# Why is this jQuery selector not selecting anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is a simple question, quick code dump. I have

```
$insides = $('<thead><tr><th><!--Blank space --></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="green-row"><td>Opportunities to Date</td></tr><tr><td>Number of wins</td></tr><tr><td>Number of active deals</td></tr><tr><td>Number of persmission to pursue</td></tr><tr><td>Number of persmission to contact</td></tr><tr><td>Number of deals lost</td></tr><tr><td>Number of deals disqualified</td></tr><tr><td id="deal%-0365">% deals with ...<input class="filterer" type="checkbox" checked="true"/></td></tr><tr><td id="deal%-VM">% deals with ...<input class="filterer" type="checkbox" checked="true"/></td></tr><tr><td id="deal%-AM">% deals with ...<input class="filterer" type="checkbox" checked="true"/></td></tr><tr><td>Current total pipeline value</td></tr></tbody></table>');
for ( var region in this.DealsByRegion ) 
{
    $insides.find('thead > tr').append('<th class="region" id="region-' + region + '">' + region + '<input class="filterer" type="checkbox" checked="true"</input>');
}
```

and it's not working because

```
$insides.find('thead > tr')
```

isn't returning anything (i.e. `$insides.find('thead > tr').length = 0`). Why? Is not `<tr><th><!--Blank space --></th></tr>` a child of a `thead` that is a descendant of `$insides`?

Comment: Why did you leave out the opening `<table>` tag?

Comment: You're missing an opening <table> tag in your $insides variable.

Comment: what is the output of `$insides.find('thead').length`?

Comment: @Pointy Because ultimately I'm filling in an existing table via `$('#data-table').append($insides);`

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't end the string with `</table>`.

Comment: @Pointy Whoops! That was a type-o.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the current root element in your `$insides` variable is already a `thead` node. So the following code:

```
$insides.find('thead > tr')
```

translates to a css selector

```
thead thead > tr
```

More appropriate selector would be:

```
$insides.filter('thead').children('tr')
```

Comment: Using `$insides.children("tr")` would select all rows, I would be better to use `$insides.filter('thead').children('tr');`

Comment: @SubparWebDev: You shouldn't. You're actually doing what is correct and intuitive. The native `querySelectorAll` would behave correctly but jQuery *intentionally* broke with the standard by arbitrarily deciding that the entire selector should be interpreted as applying to the sub structure's content only instead of the entire document like every other CSS selector.